# PERL : How to create table from an array?

Tags: arrays, regex, perl, perl-module

I have an array like this

```
@array = ( 
           1, 
           some 9-digit number-1, 
           some 9-digit number-2, 
           2, 
           some 9-digit number-3, 
           some 9-digit number-4 
           .....and so on
);
```

Now I want to print this in a table as

```
1    some 9-digit number-1  some 9-digit number-2
2    some 9-digit number-3  some 9-digit number-4
3    some 9-digit number-5  some 9-digit number-6
```

I also want to print the table to a text file. What logic would be the best ?

Thanks

Comment: I figured it out. I used Text::Table
Thanks

Comment: You should write an answer to your question showing how you solved it. That will help future visitors who have the same question.

Comment: use Text::Table;

my $tb = Text ::Table ->new( "Heading 1", "Heading 2" , Heading 3");

for ( my $i=0; $i<=$#array ; $i = $i+3) {
$tb -> load ([array[$i], array[$i+1], array[$i+2]]); }

print $tb;

Comment: Not in a comment, in an answer. Click the "Answer Your Question" button toward the bottom of the page.

Comment: This is what I see 
Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You can answer 8/9/2014 2:26:14 AM

Comment: @JohnF you should be able to answer it now (you passed 10 rep)

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. I used [`Text::Table`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Table) Thanks –  [John F](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3903035/john-f)

```
use Text::Table;
my $tb = Text::Table->new( "Heading 1", "Heading 2" , "Heading 3");

for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#array; $i += 3) {
    $tb->load([@array[$i, $i+1, $i+2]]);
}

print $tb;
```

Answer (score 1):

A module isn't really necessary for this simple task.

Here's an alternative solution that just uses [`splice`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html) and [`printf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = ( 
  1, 999999991,  999999992, 
  2, 999999993,  999999994, 
  3, 999999995,  999999996, 
);

while ( @array >= 3 ) {
  printf "%-4s %-10s %s\n", splice @array, 0, 3;
}
```

**output**

```
1    999999991  999999992
2    999999993  999999994
3    999999995  999999996
```