# Multi-dimensional array formatted to console grid/columns

Tags: arrays, perl, formatting

Using Text::Table or Text::ANSITable, or something similar...

If I have a two-dimensional array (which represents a grid of data), where the first row can be the column headers, how can I apply that data and format it into a command line grid with columns.

Something like this: [PERL : How to create table from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25209959/perl-how-to-create-table-from-an-array)

Except that the number of rows and columns is variable depending on the array setup and needs to automatically output as such.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Text::Table](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/Text-Table-1.133/lib/Text/Table.pm) to accomplish this, as it handles variable numbers of rows and columns.  Although the documentation leaves a lot to be desired, you can usually look to the test files or examples to show you how the library should actually get used.  I've adapted [example.pl](https://github.com/shlomif/Text-Table/blob/master/Text-Table/examples/Text-Table-UTF8-example.pl) to illustrate this:

**table.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use utf8;

use Text::Table;

binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';

my ($rows, $cols) = @ARGV;
$rows ||= 5;
$cols ||= 7;

my @cols = map { "column " . $_} ( 1..$cols );
my $sep = \'│';

my $major_sep = \'║';
my $tb = Text::Table->new($sep,  " Number ", $major_sep,
                          (map { +(" $_ ", $sep) } @cols)
    );

my $num_cols = @cols;

for my $row (1..$rows) {
    $tb->load([ "row $row", map { "r$row,c$_" } ( 1..$cols ) ]);
}

my $make_rule = sub {
    my ($args) = @_;

    my $left = $args->{left};
    my $right = $args->{right};
    my $main_left = $args->{main_left};
    my $middle = $args->{middle};

    return $tb->rule(
        sub {
            my ($index, $len) = @_;

            return ('─' x $len);
        },
        sub {
            my ($index, $len) = @_;

            my $char =
                (     ($index == 0) ? $left
                      : ($index == 1) ? $main_left
                      : ($index == $num_cols+1) ? $right
                      : $middle
                );

            return $char x $len;
        },
        );
};

my $start_rule = $make_rule->(
    {
        left => '┌',
        main_left => '╥',
        right => '┐',
        middle => '┬',
    }
    );

my $mid_rule = $make_rule->(
    {
        left => '├',
        main_left => '╫',
        right => '┤',
        middle => '┼',
    }
    );

my $end_rule = $make_rule->(
    {
        left => '└',
        main_left => '╨',
        right => '┘',
        middle => '┴',
    }
    );


print $start_rule, $tb->title,
    (map { $mid_rule, $_, } $tb->body()), $end_rule;
```

**output**

```
perl table.pl 3 5
┌────────╥──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ Number ║ column 1 │ column 2 │ column 3 │ column 4 │ column 5 │
├────────╫──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│row 1   ║r1,c1     │r1,c2     │r1,c3     │r1,c4     │r1,c5     │
├────────╫──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│row 2   ║r2,c1     │r2,c2     │r2,c3     │r2,c4     │r2,c5     │
├────────╫──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│row 3   ║r3,c1     │r3,c2     │r3,c3     │r3,c4     │r3,c5     │
└────────╨──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

Comment: In retrospect, my question was probably not well worded. I think in the end, the thing I didn't realize I needed was the perl "map" keyword. That's where I was failing. Your post helped me realize that and you went way above and beyond. Thanks

Comment: I just looked at this page accidentally and noticed a character you used that I had hunted for, for quite a while, as a nice separator-- ║  (I find now that it's U+2551).  Thank you!  I had apparently already upvoted your good answer, but still wanted to say thank you for revealing that character :)

Comment: You are welcome!  There is a list of them here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character#Box_Drawing

Answer (score 0):

While modules offer easier control and features, if you only need to print it out as a grid

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my @ary = ([1..3], [10..12], [100..102]);

foreach my $row (@ary) { 
    printf "%7.3f  ", $_ for @$row; 
    say ''
}
```

Prints

```
  1.000    2.000    3.000  
 10.000   11.000   12.000  
100.000  101.000  102.000
```

Choose your specifier (`%7.3f` above) accordingly to what data you have. See [sprintf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html)

If the first row is headers, `shift` it off of the array and print with the same width but using `%s`

```
my @ary = ([qw(one two three)], [1..3], [10..12], [100..102]); 

printf "%7s  ", $_ for @{shift @ary};
say '';

foreach my $row (@ary) { 
    printf "%7.3f  ", $_ for @$row; 
    say ''
}
```

This prints the same as above but with (aligned) column names in the first row.

If "*grid of data*" means numeric data, then the code can discover whether there is a header line, with a reasonable assumption that the first line contains *something* non-numeric

```
use List::Util qw(any);

my $have_header = any { /[^0-9.+-]/ } @{$ary[0]};
```

what also assumes the absence of `NaN` and `1e02` or such on the first line (can be checked).

Better yet, use `looks_like_number` from [Scalar::Util](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.9/Scalar/Util.html)

```
use List::Util qw(any);
use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);

my $have_header = any { not looks_like_number($_) } @{$ary[0]};
```

This uses Perl's [internal sense of what a number is](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.9/perlapi.html#looks_like_number), and accounts for `NaN` and exponential notation, among other things.

---

If the program needs to find out the width of columns, or they differ a lot, there is more to do for a nice output since we need the maximum width of each column.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';    
use List::Util qw(max);

my $file = shift @ARGV || 'data.txt';
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";
my @ary = map { [ split ] } <$fh>;

my @maxw = (1) x @{$ary[0]};   
for my $r (@ary) {
    for (0..$#$r) {
        my $len = length $r->[$_];
        $maxw[$_] = $len if $len > $maxw[$_]
    }
};

my $hdr = shift @ary;
printf "%$maxw[$_]s  ", $hdr->[$_] for 0..$#$hdr;
say '';

for my $i (0..$#ary) {
    printf "%-$maxw[$_].2f  ", $ary[$i]->[$_] for 0..$#{$ary[$i]};
    say '';
}
```

This expects numbers, except for the header. A few other reasonable assumptions are made.

With input `data.txt` file used to populate the array

```
one two three  
1.12 1.1 12  
1.00 10.00 102.00
```

the program prints

```
one   two     three  
1.12   1.10    12.00  
1.00  10.00   102.00
```

If there is a reason to "underline" the column names print this line right after headers

```
say join("  ", map { '-'x$maxw[$_] } 0..$#$hdr);
```

(However, tables are generally most readable when free of extra decorations.)

Note.  If the numbers are computed in the program those scalars are used as numbers and the length of the string representing them in print should be queried as `length sprintf "%s", $num`.  When they are read from a file they are taken as strings, what is used above for simplicity.

Note for another refinement.  The above uses (fixed) 2 decimal places. That can be changed, if needed, so to first count the number of decimal places in input and print out accordingly.  However, it is probably more sensible to decide on the uniform width, or at least fix the maximum width. (One doesn't want an accidental column with 16 decimal places, most useless!)